# RU cost of multi master account

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Our Cosmos DB has 3 global regions and multi-master is enabled. We only index few things, so I think the indexing won't cost much. The calculator shows that upserting one 2MB document should cost 1250 RU per region.
[image]
However, the request charge we get from response is 7512.58.

> RequestStartTime: 2020-05-12T00:22:59.1387647Z, RequestEndTime:
>   2020-05-12T00:22:59.2492807Z,  Number of regions attempted:1
>   ResponseTime: 2020-05-12T00:22:59.2492807Z, StoreResult:
>   StorePhysicalAddress:
>   rntbd://sn4prdddc07-docdb-2.documents.azure.com:14090/apps/f5b76cfe-f8cb-4079-8e0a-f1d5062ab650/services/584a5bbb-51ba-4911-b85f-65cb3d036d77/partitions/eacdf9bb-7b21-43ec-892c-f9d39360bec4/replicas/132323144644691971p/,
>   LSN: 37839654, GlobalCommittedLsn: 37839653, PartitionKeyRangeId: 53,
>   IsValid: True, StatusCode: 200, SubStatusCode: 0, **RequestCharge:
>   7512.58**, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: 48#37839654#2=19712326#5=20410763, UsingLocalLSN: False,
>   TransportException: null, ResourceType: Document, OperationType:
>   Upsert

The second weird thing is the normalized RU consumption can reach 100% sometimes even the provisioned throughput is 11.72k RU/s on each **physical partition** but we only upsert 2MB document for 2 times on one same partition in one second.

My questions are:

1. How to understand the request charge of 7512.58? It's about 6 times as the capacity calculator shows. So I guess the number takes the 3 global regions(x3) and multi-master(x2) into consideration?
2. Why RU consumption can reach 100% when we provision 11.72k RU/s per physical partition and there are only 2 upsert on one physical partition in one second? Is this expected?

Similar question: [How does CosmosDb charge RUs for write operations in a multi-master enironment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53921930/how-does-cosmosdb-charge-rus-for-write-operations-in-a-multi-master-enironment)

Comment: Your error message implies that you're performing an *upsert*, vs an *insert*, which likely explains the additional cost. What happens if you just do an *insert*? Also - just an aside, I'd re-examine your data schema to see if you can reduce document size. 2MB seems excessively large (I usually only see documents that large when there is binary, non-metadata content, or unbounded arrays).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Our scenario needs both update and insert, so we have to use upsert. The reported cost is 6 times as estimated, which should not only be "additional cost". And yes, we are working on reducing our document size.